# I got this Warning: DatePickerAndroid has been merged

Tags: vue.js, vue-native

right after I created a new project I got this Warning

> Warning: DatePickerAndroid has been merged with DatePickerIOS and will
>   be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported
>   from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker' instead of
>   'react-native'. See
>   https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-datetimepicker

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHvYs.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I also get those. You can safely ignore it and some other similar messages. Looks like they are aware of it and working on a fix:
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/vue-native-core/issues/239

Answer (score 0):

In a Vue Native project 3 warning messages were appearing in the Dev environment.  To suppress these the following code was added in the app.vue file:

```
import { LogBox } from "react-native";
```

then in the created() lifecycle hook -

```
created() {
    LogBox.ignoreLogs([
      'DatePickerIOS has been merged with DatePickerAndroid and will be removed in a future release.',
      'StatusBarIOS has been merged with StatusBar and will be removed in a future release.',
      'DatePickerAndroid has been merged with DatePickerIOS and will be removed in a future release.'
    ]);
  }
```